# How to set entire enum list in a variable and then save it in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, enums, pojo

I need to save Enum data in MongoDB, for this I am able to get the Enum data but not getting how to set it. I am using Enum in a POJO and need to save that POJO containing Enum in MongoDB, used Gson for this.

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Coverage1 {
    public  enum Coverage {
Hearing_Aid_Professional_Liability("HEAR"), Incidental_Motorized_Land_Conveyances_Liability_Only("LANDC"), PremisesOperations_334("PREM"), Rental_Reimbursement("RREIM"), Liquor_Law_Liability_332("LLL"), Wind("WIND"), Business_Personal_Property("BPP"), OpticianOptometrists_Professional_Liability("OOPRL"), Builders_Risk("BLDRK"), Incidental_Farming_Personal_Liability("IFPL");

    private String val;

Coverage(String val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal ()
    {
        return this.val;
    }

    public void setVal (String val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

    public Coverage value;
    public Coverage getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Coverage value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private String id;

    private CoverageCd coverageCd;
    private CoverageDesc coverageDesc;
    private CoverageTypeCd coverageTypeCd;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   public CoverageCd getCoverageCd() {
        return coverageCd;
    }

    public void setCoverageCd(CoverageCd coverageCd) {
        this.coverageCd = coverageCd;
    }
   public CoverageDesc getCoverageDesc() {
        return coverageDesc;
    }

    public void setCoverageDesc(CoverageDesc coverageDesc) {
        this.coverageDesc = coverageDesc;
    }*
    public CoverageTypeCd getCoverageTypeCd() {
        return coverageTypeCd;
    }

     public void setCoverageTypeCd(CoverageTypeCd coverageTypeCd) {
        this.coverageTypeCd = coverageTypeCd;
    }

}
```

In another class I am calling it from where i need to save it in Mongo DB.

```
Coverage1 cv= new Coverage1();
            List<Coverage1.Coverage> ae= new ArrayList<Coverage1.Coverage>();
            for(Coverage1.Coverage enumval:Coverage1.Coverage.values()){
                //ae=enumval;
                System.out.println(enumval);
                cv.setValue(enumval);//I need to set the entire Enum data here, so that it could be saved in Mongo. But not getting how to save the entire data
            }
            cv.setId("1");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(cv);
            System.out.println(json);
            // Parse to bson document and insert
           Document doc = Document.parse(json);
           db.getCollection("NameColl").insertOne(doc);
```

Please someone help me how to save the entire Enum data in Mongo document.

Comment: There is only one `cv` object and you are overwriting its one value attribute each time through the loop.  How exactly do you expect to save a list there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could regenerate the correct schema with a list of your coverage values in your JSON, but this needs to be a list

```
public Coverage1.Coverage[] values;
```

Therefore, change the getters and setters as well.

Then, you can `cv.setValues(Coverage1.Coverage.values());`

Or maybe, you tried to do this

```
List<Coverage1.Coverage> ae= new ArrayList<Coverage1.Coverage>(Arrays.asList( Coverage1.Coverage.values());
```

Or,

```
for(Coverage1.Coverage enumval: Coverage1.Coverage.values() ){
    ae.add(enumval);
}
```

Basically, `cv.setValue(enumval);` can't be done in a loop because you'll overwrite the one `value`

I'd also suggest better names for the enum. And the one at the end of `Coverage1` could be removed

Comment: This is still not working, Getting error: Cannot convert from Coverage1.Coverage to List<Coverage1.Coverage>. Here Coverage1 is the class name and Coverage is Enum name. Please suggest

Comment: You need to completely replace `public Coverage value;` with a list. That was my point